# Javascript Remove entry from array where id = myid value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list of containers and I've added a delete button so I can delete the selected one. 
It this point I know its id.

Here's the data:

```
this.data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Container 1',
},
{
    id: 5,
    title: 'Container 2',
}];
```

I'm trying:

```
removeIT(id) {
    this.data = this.data.filter(id);
}
```

But it's removing nothing. How can I do this?

Comment: you want to remove total object?

Comment: And what is the value of `id` you are passing?

Comment: The function sintax is not correct.

Comment: Yes, the total entry for a particular id

Comment: Then value I'm passing in the id is 1

Comment: `filter` takes a function as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
removeIT(id) {
  this.data = this.data.filter(function(obj) { return obj.id !== id; });
}
```

Filter function take a predicate (fancy name for a function that returns a boolean) and returns the array containing  all elements for which predicate is true

Comment: It does not run in JavaScript.

Comment: You shouldn't use arrow functions in answers without explaining that it 100% does not work in IE and most likely never will.

Comment: Im my case I'm using Angular so it fine as it will get translated on the dist

Comment: Syntactically is not ok.

Answer (score 3):

```js
data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Container 1',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Container 2',
  }
];

removeById( 1 );
console.log( data );

function removeById( id ) {
  for ( var i in data )
    if ( data[ i ].id == id )
      data.splice( i, 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const removeIT = (id) => (
    data.filter(function(e) {
      return(e.id !== id);
    })
)
```